# How can i return custom error message into .erb file by rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I need to return the custom message if params from the form doesn't pass my condition.

This is my code now.

```
def update
   @admin_user = AdminUser.find(params[:id])

    if @admin_user.authenticate(params[:admin_user][:old_password])
      if @admin_user.update_attributes(update_user_params)

      else
        render 'edit'
      end
    else
      render 'edit' , :errors => "wrong old password"
    end

end
```

It seems like this didn't work out with this list

```
<% object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
```

So how can i fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bit is the bit that didn't work?
`render 'edit' , :errors => "wrong old password"`

```
if @admin_user.authenticate(params[:admin_user][:old_password])
  #code
else
  @admin_user.errors[:base] << "wrong old password"
  render 'edit'
end
```